# Unable to open the design interface of winform application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I created a new program to add controls from the design interface, but when I open the design interface, the following error pops up.The error says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using ? Is there any special components on your Form ? A form design mode crash is often caused by errors in Form1.designer.cs, make sure you check that file for warnings and other messages.

Comment: You have deleted some objects/controls in your Form but there's still a reference around that something is trying to use. Or, you have modified *manually* the `Form.designer.cs` file, removing *something* partially, or you have removed a Project Resource, but that reference is still there somewhere, or the Form crashed after an invalid object has generated an exception and you ignored the warning not to continue without fixing the exception first. Take a look at the `Error List` panel (`CTRL +\, E`) to check for error/warnings notifications.

Comment: Kindly clarify the VS version (eg 2019 or v16.6) and .Net, is it Full or Core? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio 2019 cannot use the form designer when developing Windows Forms app (. Net core) applications.

According to the description of Microsoft developer blog, we can use Visual Studio 2019 preview channel to update visual studio 2019 to 16.6 to enable the designer. Without the preview channel enabled.

we can still make the project support the form designer by changing the project file. When we create a new. Net core Windows Forms program, our project file (*. csproj) usually contains the following:

[image]

The target framework tag indicates that the target framework of our program is. net core app3.1.

If our project can support the. Net framework at the same time, we can use the designer in visual studio, and we can use the target frameworks label to make the project support multiple target frameworks:

[image]

After saving your changes, visual studio may prompt for a reload. Confirm the reload and the form designer will be ready to use.

result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your Winform code find the `InitializeComponent();`

```
class Foo : System.Windows.Forms
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Put the cursor on the InitializeComponent and press F12 or right click it and Goto Definition.

It will open up the Foo.Designer.cs file which contains the designer created code.

You will see a `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]` Attribute wrapping the partial form class - comment out this attribute. Put a breakpoint on the InitializeComponent() line and F5 to run the program.

You will find an object that is being called that is null - typical NRE.

Comment: What is "No Debugger" attribute? Never seen such in winforms. Afaik exceptions stack trace will lead all the way into `InitializeComponents()` without need to do any extra stuff. OP has to show full exception (not sure how to catch it, perhaps try/catch around call to it).

Comment: @Sinatr  There were two attributes to control the debugger behavior: `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]` on the `Dispose` method override and `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]` right before `InitializeComponent()`. New versions of VS don't add these (iirc, unless you opt-in).

Comment: @Sinatr - in the Designer file its pretty hard to miss the only Attributes. *OP has to show full exception* - OK let me explain this, the Exception is a NRE the only thing you're going to see is the error "Object not set to instance" and the StackTrace doesn't provide much useful info further than `InitializeComponents()`. Here I give the OP a way to debug it, teaching how to solve the issue without exceptions. Try it yourself, corrupt the Designer code, then wrap the InitializeComponents() in a try/catch - it's nonsense advice. I've edited the question so downvotes can be reversed or removed.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, it's not my downvote. And since I don't see such attributes in my own winforms project I can't upvote either. I've searched for a word "debuggerstep" in the folder containing ~50 of my winforms projects and didn't find any reference. It may be VS version dependent, I am using VS2017, some of projects were created by VS2015, not sure about ealier versions.

Comment: @Sinatr - this is important. In WinForms there's a designer file, a Partial Form Class. The way the Form Designer works is via the `InitiailizeCompontent` to seperate Form Design from the class methods and events. You have the attributes by default, unless someone else has deleted them?